# Generators in C#?

Tags: c#, iterator, generator, enumerable

In javascript I can create a generator which would behave like this:

```
function* idMaker(){
  var index = 0;
  while(true)
    yield index++;
}

var gen = idMaker();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2
```

What would the C# equivalent look like?

I wonder whether this will work:

```
static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> MakeId()
{
  int index = 0;
  while (true)
    yield return index++;
}
```

but from what I understand of C# so far, the above wouldn't work as I intend and instead infinite loop.

Comment: The C# version returns like a function, so `while (true)` will lock up you application until you run out of RAM.

Comment: Why it won't behave as you intent?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I know, so what is the C# equivalent. Does it even have generators?

Comment: The yield keyword makes the generator lazy evaluated, so the while loop keeps being interrupted and doesn't run forever.

Comment: The first version is also an infinite loop if you keep pulling it for more values, just as the C# version, in this respect they're identical.

Comment: "I wonder whether this will work" Well, try it.

Comment: See it working: http://ideone.com/PVvkww

Answer (score 9):

You can do the same with your MakeId in the following way:

```
using (var gen = MakeId().GetEnumerator()) {
    gen.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(gen.Current); // 0
    gen.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(gen.Current); // 1
    gen.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(gen.Current); // 2
}
```

If you don't like to call `MoveNext` all the time, you can write extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static T NextValue<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator) {
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        return enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Then it becomes

```
using (var gen = MakeId().GetEnumerator()) {                
    Console.WriteLine(gen.NextValue()); // 0                
    Console.WriteLine(gen.NextValue()); // 1                
    Console.WriteLine(gen.NextValue()); // 2
}
```

Comment: The first example here, is basically what a `foreach` does.

Comment: Yes, but OP seems to want to do that without foreach, Say I need one id, then do something, then need second id, etc. Or want to store generator in some field.

Comment: I'm just pointing it out. Someone learning C# might not know about it.

Comment: But the function I wrote would still hang right? Because of the infinite loop? So, this still doesn't work to my understanding.

Comment: @minseong no it won't hang. It's iterator, so (in simple terms) when you call MoveNext, it executes the code to the next yield return statement and then returns. Of course to do that, your function is internally rewritten as a state machine. Basically the same as in your javascript example, there it will not hang in infinite loop, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `C#` equivalent to your code is:

```
static void Main()
{
    var enumerator = MakeId().GetEnumerator();

    enumerator.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current); // 0    
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current); // 1    
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current); // 2

}

static IEnumerable<int> MakeId()
{
  int index = 0;
  while (true)
    yield return index++;
}
```

`GetEnumerator` returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.

Comment: Changing `index++` to `++index` makes the enumerator start with `1`. You're covering that up by inspecting `Current` prior to the first `MoveNext()`, which isn't valid.